# Linear-gradient is not responsive on Chrome but responsive on FireFox why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote this code for live background gradient Generator but it is not working on google chrome but working on firefox what am i doing wrong ?

```js
var color1 = document.querySelector(".color1");
var color2 = document.querySelector(".color2");
var body = document.getElementById("gradient");

function doGradient() {
  body.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, " +
    color1.value +
    "," +
    color2.value +
    ")";
}

color1.addEventListener("input", doGradient)
color2.addEventListener("input", doGradient)

doGradient();
```

```html
<body id="gradient">
  <h1>Gradient Generator</h1>
  <input class="color1" type="color" name="color1" value="#00ff00">
  <input class="color2" type="color" name="color2" value="#ff0000">
  <h2>CSS Background</h2>
</body>
```

not responsive or live on Google Chrome but work prefectly on firefox

Comment: Tested your code in Chrome and it works just fine. Do you see any error messages in the console?

Comment: i again check it but still not working live on chrome but working prefectly on firefox

Comment: I can confirm it works just fine in both browsers, so you'll have to add more details. Desktop or mobile? Which version of Chrome? What does the dev console say in terms of warnings or errors, have you made sure not to run any extensions that can interfere, etc

Comment: i restart the browser and even update it and close all extension but still not working on chrome there is no error on the console also and i even check it on code pen but still same thing is happening on chrome but not on firefox btw what i am saying is it not work responsively or live in other words

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to call the `doGradient` in the EventListener. But after @Jon's edit, he added calling the function.

```
color1.addEventListener("input", doGradient())
```

Try it like this and I hope it solves the issue.

### Edit:

If you want to apply the gradient after selecting another color, you should use `change` event listener instead of `input`.

Comment: acutally on .addEventListener we don't call the fucntion it automatically do it when we click or have input according to my knowledge

Comment: @FahadMir I think when we have a trigger we don't have to call the function. but you wrote addEventListener on `input` instead of `change`.